# How to bind custom type objects and controls?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have an objects array of my custom type. And I have a button array related with these objects. I want to change any object by clicking on his button. So buttons must "know" about their objects. And objects must "know" about their buttons. How to bind them each other (one object binds with only one button and vice versa)?

In addition, it must be in C# code, not XAML, because I'll construct these arrays dinamically.

Example. There are Map object with Cell objects in it (VM means view model):

```
public class MapCellVM
{
    public bool IsPassable { get; set; }
}

public class MapVM
{   
    public MapCellVM[,] CellMap { get; set; }
}
```

Each cell must be presented as a button. So the user can change IsPassable property of any cell object just by clicking on particular button.

Comment: Please provide a code example and more information on what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you realized your issue so far, so I can just give you an example how I would have designed it. As you want to show a list of custom objects I would use an `ItemsControl` to show them and a command on each custom object which is triggered from XAML. That would still give you the chance to handle everything in code. Here is a sample:

**Custom object**

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; private set; }

    public CustomObject()
    {
        DoSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoSomething);
    }

    private void DoSomething(object obj)
    {
        // TODO: do something
    }
}
```

If you're not already using an implementation of `DelegateCommand`, have a look at the source of it in Prism (or anywhere else, there are a lot of samples).

**MainWindow (part of the XAML)**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Do Something" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**MainWindow (Code behind)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomObject> _customObjects;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _customObjects = new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();
        Loaded += MainWindowLoaded;
    }

    private void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemsControl.ItemsSource = _customObjects;
        _customObjects.Add(new CustomObject());
    }
}
```

That's it. Every time you click the button the method `DoSomething` is executed.